# Blue screen of Death when rendering using cycles. (DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Not sure if this is the right place as this might be more of a windows issue but I am honestly out of ideas. I recently helped my gf build a new pc primarily for her blender use. It has the following hardware:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- Nvidia 3060 Ventus 12gb
- 16gb ram
- 750 w Corsair psu
- MSI MAG B550 tomahawk motherboard

Software:
Windows 11

When trying to render quite a complex scene using cycles it instantly blue screens. When checking what went wrong though windbg I get the folowing:

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff8056a0b7013, address which referenced memory

### Debugging Details:

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

```
Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 1500

Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 1874

Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 140

Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 3333

Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 110

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
Value: 0xd1

Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
Value: 808

Key  : Dump.Attributes.KernelGeneratedTriageDump
Value: 1

Key  : Failure.Bucket
Value: AV_rcbottom!unknown_function

Key  : Failure.Hash
Value: {57ce7b09-5d1c-85d4-91e1-3d4e1c91bdfa}

Key  : Hypervisor.Enlightenments.ValueHex
Value: 1497cf94

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AnyHypervisorPresent
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicVirtualizationAvailable
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AsyncMemoryHint
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CoreSchedulerRequested
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CpuManager
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DeprecateAutoEoi
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DynamicCpuDisabled
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Epf
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ExtendedProcessorMasks
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.HardwareMbecAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MaxBankNumber
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MemoryZeroingControl
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoExtendedRangeFlush
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoNonArchCoreSharing
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Phase0InitDone
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.PowerSchedulerQos
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.RootScheduler
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.SynicAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.UseQpcBias
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Value
Value: 4853999

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ValueHex
Value: 4a10ef

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VpAssistPage
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VsmAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.AccessStats
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CrashdumpEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CreateVirtualProcessor
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.DisableHyperthreading
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HostTimelineSync
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HypervisorDebuggingEnabled
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.IsHyperV
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.LivedumpEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MapDeviceInterrupt
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MceEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Nested
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.StartLogicalProcessor
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Value
Value: 1015

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.ValueHex
Value: 3f7
```

BUGCHECK_CODE:  d1

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff8056a0b7013

FILE_IN_CAB:  010124-8265-01.dmp

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x808
Kernel Generated Triage Dump

WRITE_ADDRESS: fffff80567f1d470: Unable to get MiVisibleState
Unable to get NonPagedPoolStart
Unable to get NonPagedPoolEnd
Unable to get PagedPoolStart
Unable to get PagedPoolEnd
unable to get nt!MmSpecialPagesInUse
0000000000000000

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffb880e4615ee0 -- (.trap 0xffffb880e4615ee0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000100
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8056a0b7013 rsp=ffffb880e4616070 rbp=ffffa8820bbf5000
r8=0000000000000800  r9=0000000000000000 r10=ffffa881eb0101a0
r11=ffffa8820db013b0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
rcbottom+0x7013:
fffff805`6a0b7013 4c8904d6        mov     qword ptr [rsi+rdx*8],r8 ds:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

STACK_TEXT:
ffffb880`e4615d98 fffff805`6762c4e9     : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb880`e4615da0 fffff805`67627a34     : 00000000`00000000 fffff805`67480b97 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000022 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
ffffb880`e4615ee0 fffff805`6a0b7013     : ffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffcf00`ab400000 fffff805`67e69a80 fffff805`67469099 : nt!KiPageFault+0x474
ffffb880`e4616070 ffffa882`0ba03b00     : ffffcf00`ab400000 fffff805`67e69a80 fffff805`67469099 ffffa882`0ba03b00 : rcbottom+0x7013
ffffb880`e4616078 ffffcf00`ab400000     : fffff805`67e69a80 fffff805`67469099 ffffa882`0ba03b00 0000577d`f45fc4f8 : 0xffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffb880`e4616080 fffff805`67e69a80     : fffff805`67469099 ffffa882`0ba03b00 0000577d`f45fc4f8 0000577d`f45fc4f8 : 0xffffcf00`ab400000
ffffb880`e4616088 fffff805`67469099     : ffffa882`0ba03b00 0000577d`f45fc4f8 0000577d`f45fc4f8 fffff805`69acc384 : nt!MiState+0x4940
ffffb880`e4616090 0000577e`12d33ff8     : ffffa881`ed550e70 fffff805`00000001 ffffa882`0bbf5000 fffff805`00000001 : nt!MiUnlockWorkingSetShared+0x69
ffffb880`e46160c0 ffffa881`ed550e70     : fffff805`00000001 ffffa882`0bbf5000 fffff805`00000001 ffffa881`ed0a9c50 : 0x0000577e`12d33ff8 ffffb880`e46160c8 fffff805`00000001     : ffffa882`0bbf5000 fffff805`00000001 ffffa881`ed0a9c50 fffff805`69acc861 : 0xffffa881`ed550e70
ffffb880`e46160d0 ffffa882`0bbf5000     : fffff805`00000001 ffffa881`ed0a9c50 fffff805`69acc861 00000000`00000001 : 0xfffff805`00000001 ffffb880`e46160d8 fffff805`00000001     : ffffa881`ed0a9c50 fffff805`69acc861 00000000`00000001 fffff805`675b6037 : 0xffffa882`0bbf5000
ffffb880`e46160e0 ffffa881`ed0a9c50     : fffff805`69acc861 00000000`00000001 fffff805`675b6037 00000000`00000168 : 0xfffff805`00000001 ffffb880`e46160e8 fffff805`69acc861     : 00000000`00000001 fffff805`675b6037 00000000`00000168 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffa881`ed0a9c50
ffffb880`e46160f0 fffff805`675c9775     : 00000000`00001800 00000000`00000000 ffffa881`f6824f20 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxDmaScatterGatherTransaction::_AdapterListControl+0xa1 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\src\dma\base\fxdmatransactionscattergather.cpp @ 460]
ffffb880`e4616130 fffff805`69acc4f2     : ffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffa881`ed205c80 ffffa881`f68246f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalBuildScatterGatherListV2+0x1f5
ffffb880`e46161c0 fffff805`69ade897     : ffffa882`0ba03b00 0000577d`f45fc4f8 ffffa882`0ba03bb8 00000000`00000001 : Wdf01000!FxDmaScatterGatherTransaction::BuildScatterGatherList+0x160 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\inc\private\FxDmaTransactionScatterGather.hpp @ 256]
ffffb880`e4616270 fffff805`69acc770     : ffffa882`00000100 ffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffb880`e46163f9 ffffa881`ed550e70 : Wdf01000!FxDmaScatterGatherTransaction::StageTransfer+0x167 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\src\dma\base\fxdmatransactionscattergather.cpp @ 379]
ffffb880`e46162e0 fffff805`69acca15     : ffffa881`ed0a9c50 00000000`00100000 ffffa881`f68246f0 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxDmaScatterGatherTransaction::StartTransfer+0x10 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\src\dma\base\fxdmatransactionscattergather.cpp @ 282]
ffffb880`e4616310 fffff805`69acbff3     : ffffa881`ed550e70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffa881`f68246f0 : Wdf01000!FxDmaTransactionBase::Execute+0xc1 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\src\dma\base\fxdmatransactionbase.cpp @ 438]
ffffb880`e4616360 fffff805`6a0bd759     : ffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffa881`ed550cf0 ffffb880`e46163f9 ffffa881`ed2cc2f0 : Wdf01000!imp_WdfDmaTransactionExecute+0x33 [minkernel\wdf\framework\kmdf\src\dma\base\fxdmatransactionapi.cpp @ 540]
ffffb880`e4616390 ffffa882`0ba03b00     : ffffa881`ed550cf0 ffffb880`e46163f9 ffffa881`ed2cc2f0 ffffa881`f68246f0 : rcbottom+0xd759
ffffb880`e4616398 ffffa881`ed550cf0     : ffffb880`e46163f9 ffffa881`ed2cc2f0 ffffa881`f68246f0 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffa882`0ba03b00 ffffb880`e46163a0 ffffb880`e46163f9     : ffffa881`ed2cc2f0 ffffa881`f68246f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00100000 : 0xffffa881`ed550cf0
ffffb880`e46163a8 ffffa881`ed2cc2f0     : ffffa881`f68246f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00100000 00000000`00000001 : 0xffffb880`e46163f9 ffffb880`e46163b0 ffffa881`f68246f0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00100000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00100000 : 0xffffa881`ed2cc2f0
ffffb880`e46163b8 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00100000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00100000 0000577d`f45fc4f8 : 0xffffa881`f68246f0

SYMBOL_NAME:  rcbottom+7013

MODULE_NAME: rcbottom

IMAGE_NAME:  rcbottom.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  7013

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_rcbottom!unknown_function

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {57ce7b09-5d1c-85d4-91e1-3d4e1c91bdfa}

Followup:     MachineOwner

---

I have tried everything I could find on the internet but nothing has worked. I have tried clean installs of the cpu as well as the gpu driver through Geforce experience, both the studio variant as well as the gaming variant, zero effect, I have done a DISM scan, a SFO scan and repair and did a memory diagnostic but to no avail. The only thing I have on my mind that could possibly work is downgrading to windows 10 to see if that has any effect, but I'd rather not because of the loss of data. I have also tried multiple versions of blender but the same exact thing happens everytime.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before, or is aware of a fix?

Comment: I would report this as a bug directly to blender.  In Blender choose -Help- -Report A bug-